# AsyncTask isn't working perfectly to get html content of webpages

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am a beginner here and was following a tutorial which uses Async task to get a Webpage in my Logcat but my app is only able to secure pages from very few sites, on many it return blank or produces HTML in a very unreadable format. Also, as AsyncTask is getting deprecated can you please tell how to perform the same function in an efficient way. Maybe using handler, Volley, Retrofit, services or something else. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public class downloadPage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try{
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inside = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inside);
            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1){
                char current = (char) data;
                 result += current;

                 data = reader.read();
            }

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Here is","The error",e);
        }

        return "Task Done";
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    downloadPage page = new downloadPage();
    String result = null;
    try {
        result = page.execute("https://docs.python.org/3/").get();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("TAG","this is the error",e);
    }
    Log.i("Result is",result);
}}
```

Although I get the HTML but I still get some errors in my logcat. Here it is-

```
10-12 19:11:18.101 16464-16464/? I/webcontentintr: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-12 19:11:18.173 16464-16464/? I/webcontentintr: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
10-12 19:11:18.176 16464-16464/? W/webcontentintr: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
10-12 19:11:18.605 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro D/ApplicationLoaders: Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.test.base.jar
10-12 19:11:18.607 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro I/webcontentintr: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
10-12 19:11:19.021 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro W/webcontentintr: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exist.
10-12 19:11:19.035 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro I/chatty: uid=10169(com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro) identical 9 lines
10-12 19:11:19.035 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro W/webcontentintr: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exist.
10-12 19:11:19.304 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
10-12 19:11:19.308 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
10-12 19:11:19.326 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
10-12 19:11:19.741 16464-16499/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
10-12 19:11:19.847 16464-16499/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
10-12 19:11:19.879 16464-16499/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
10-12 19:11:20.407 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro I/webcontentintr: IncrementDisableThreadFlip blocked for 7.872ms
10-12 19:11:20.455 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro I/webcontentintr: Waiting for a blocking GC ClassLinker
10-12 19:11:20.573 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro I/webcontentintr: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ClassLinker on ClassLinker for 117.552ms
10-12 19:11:20.574 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro W/webcontentintr: Verification of void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener(android.view.View, android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerCompat) took 119.090ms (604.58 bytecodes/s) (1784B approximate peak alloc)
10-12 19:11:20.745 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro W/webcontentintr: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
10-12 19:11:20.748 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro W/webcontentintr: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
10-12 19:11:22.545 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro I/Result is: <html>
                                                                                <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
                                                                                <body bgcolor="white">
                                                                                <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
                                                                                <hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
                                                                                </body>
                                                                                </html>
10-12 19:11:22.678 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro V/StudioProfiler: StudioProfilers agent attached.
10-12 19:11:22.828 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro W/webcontentintr: DexFile /data/user/0/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro/perfa.jar is in boot class path but is not in a known location
10-12 19:11:22.843 16464-16540/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro V/StudioProfiler: Acquiring Application for Events
10-12 19:11:22.663 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro W/webcontentintro: type=1400 audit(0.0:705): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/user/0/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro/libperfa_x86.so" dev="vdc" ino=131501 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro
10-12 19:11:22.880 16464-16541/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro W/InputMethodManager: InputMethodManager.getInstance() is deprecated because it cannot be compatible with multi-display. Use context.getSystemService(InputMethodManager.class) instead.
                                                                                         java.lang.Throwable
                                                                                             at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.getInstance(InputMethodManager.java:1234)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at com.android.tools.profiler.support.profilers.EventProfiler$InputConnectionHandler.run(EventProfiler.java:287)
                                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
10-12 19:11:22.902 16464-16541/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro W/InputMethodManager: InputMethodManager.peekInstance() is deprecated because it cannot be compatible with multi-display. Use context.getSystemService(InputMethodManager.class) instead.
                                                                                         java.lang.Throwable
                                                                                             at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.peekInstance(InputMethodManager.java:1253)
                                                                                             at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.getInstance(InputMethodManager.java:1239)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at com.android.tools.profiler.support.profilers.EventProfiler$InputConnectionHandler.run(EventProfiler.java:287)
                                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
10-12 19:11:23.215 16464-16464/com.example.vaibhav.webcontentintro A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 16464 (webcontentintro), pid 16464 (webcontentintro)
```

Also with a bit of online search I got to know that not closing connection can lead to memory troubles and using get method is not optimal as it can freeze the UI for 3-5 seconds. So, what other method can I use in place of that.

Comment: Try using Thread instead of asyntask ,It might works for you

Comment: Can you give me an example or website from where I can see how is Handler deployed to obtain webpages. @SahilGoyal